# 3 csv files, summing everyfile and then summing all together

Tags: java

I've got a task to make a program which calculates sum from 3 csv files, first for each file and then at the end to sum all together and to print it out. I've made a solution but when running program it doesnt print anything. Check working directory and its good.

```
public class MoneyCounter  {

        public void count(Path path) throws Exception {

            Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

                    int[] amount = {0, 0, 0};

                    if (file.endsWith("csv")) {

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Files.newInputStream(file)));

                        while(reader.ready()){
                            String line = reader.readLine();
                            if(line.split(" ")[1].equals("EUR")) amount[0] += Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[2]);
                            else if(line.split(" ")[1].equals("HRK")) amount[1] += Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[2]);
                            else amount[2] += Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[2]);
                        }

                        System.out.println("\"" + file + "\"" + " found");
                        System.out.println("\t Totals by currencies: ");

                        System.out.println("Money in all countries: ");
                        if(amount[0] > 0 ) System.out.println("\t EUR: " + amount[0]);
                        if(amount[1] > 0 ) System.out.println("\t HRK: " + amount[1]);
                        if(amount[2] > 0 ) System.out.println("\t USD: " + amount[2]);
                    }
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MoneyCounter moneyCounter = new MoneyCounter();
        moneyCounter.count(new File("path.csv").toPath());
    }
}
```

Comment: How data are stored in csv?

Answer (score 1):

[Path.endsWith(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) doesn't do what you think, it checks if the last "element" of the path **is equal** to the given string.

> for example, the path "foo/bar" ends with "foo/bar" and "bar"
>
> It does not end with "r" or "/bar"

Try to call `file.toString().endsWith("csv")`  instead.

Comment: Tried your solution but ended with this errorException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
 at com.dino.MoneyCounter$1.visitFile(MoneyCounter.java:27)
 at com.dino.MoneyCounter$1.visitFile(MoneyCounter.java:15)
 at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2724)
 at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2796)
 at com.dino.MoneyCounter.count(MoneyCounter.java:15)
 at com.dino.MoneyCounter.main(MoneyCounter.java:47)

Answer (score 0):

It is not satifying endWith condition.
Check below Working code.

```
package files;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Test.count(new File("d:\\Files").toPath());
    }

    private static void count(Path path) throws IOException {
        Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {

                int[] amount = { 0, 0, 0 };
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Files.newInputStream(file)));

                while (reader.ready()) {
                    String line = reader.readLine();

                    if (line.split(" ")[1].equals("EUR"))
                        amount[0] += Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[2]);
                    else if (line.split(" ")[1].equals("HRK"))
                        amount[1] += Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[2]);
                    else
                        amount[2] += Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[2]);
                }

                System.out.println("\"" + file + "\"" + " found");
                System.out.println("\t Totals by currencies: ");

                System.out.println("Money in all countries: ");
                if (amount[0] > 0)
                    System.out.println("\t EUR: " + amount[0]);
                if (amount[1] > 0)
                    System.out.println("\t HRK: " + amount[1]);
                if (amount[2] > 0)
                    System.out.println("\t USD: " + amount[2]);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

There are  csv files under D://Files/a.csv with following data.

a.csv

EUR 10

b.csv

HRK 20

c.csv

USD 30

Result :

Totals by currencies:

Money in all countries:

```
 EUR: 10
 HRK: 20
```

Totals by currencies:

Money in all countries:

```
 HRK: 20
```

Totals by currencies:

Money in all countries:

```
 USD: 10
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "application"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
 at com.dino.Main$1.visitFile(Main.java:37)
 at com.dino.Main$1.visitFile(Main.java:22)
 at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2724)
 at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2796)
 at com.dino.Main.count(Main.java:22) at com.dino.Main.main(Main.java:18)

Comment: try running code with 3 separate files and everyfile has three different currencies what will you get?

Comment: i know i might be boring, but you have helped a ton. I've got one more question to ask. You made it with 3 files that have only one row in it. Could you check what will you get if u have files like this: 1st - http://prntscr.com/mbg43o 2nd - http://prntscr.com/mbg4aa and 3rd - http://prntscr.com/mbg4fi